# Drawing line outside of axis in d3js line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been trying to create a dynamic line chart in d3.js, using the tutorial [here](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2014/09/19/interactive.html). I have almost got it working, but there is a slight problem. When I choose a date interval using the viewport and redraw the chart, it draws the line outside of the axis too. See the left of the graphic below.

[image]

Normally, I draw the line as below:

```
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function (d) {
                    return xScale(d.timestamp);
                })
                .y(function (d) {
                    return yScale(d.value);
                });

plotChart.append("path")
                .attr("class", "line")
                .attr("id", "lineGraphId")
                .attr("d", valueline(data));
```

And my redraw chart function is as below:

```
function redrawChart() {
            plotChart.select("#lineGraphId").remove();
            plotChart.append("path")
                    .attr("class", "line")
                    .attr("id", "lineGraphId")
                    .attr("d", valueline(data));
            plotChart.select('.x.axis').call(xAxis);
        }
```

I could not find a solution for drawing outside of the axis. I could not host my code in jsfiddle because I needed to load a csv data, but you can see all source code [here](http://goktugerce.com/d3js/week.html).

Comment: do you mean how not to draw the line out of the y-axis?

Comment: @phoa yes, should have worded it better.

Comment: If you're following the tutorial.. you probably miss applying the clip path to the plotArea. Look for `clipPath`

Comment: @phoa oh yeah, that solved the problem. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I needed to add this line of code to redrawChart function:

```
.attr('clip-path', 'url(#plotAreaClip)')
```